# How do I get the items in this ArrayList and assign them to variables?

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I am using SQLite with Android. I am saving some of the transactions in a table called sale. I can get all the items in the table like this.

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> getAllItems() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SALE_TABLE_NAME, null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put(SALE_ITEM_ID, res.getInt(0));
            hashMap.put(SALE_ITEM_NAME, res.getString(1));
            hashMap.put(SALE_AMOUNT, res.getString(2));
            array_list.add(hashMap);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

 public int getMaxId() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id) FROM " + SALE_TABLE_NAME, null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        return res.getInt(0);
    }
```

in the activity class where I call this function, its like this `dBHelper.getAllitems()`. I want to be able to get all the items and ids pulled from that assign them to stand alone variables. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your DB in your Activitiy's onCreate method then write a helper class to avoid boiler plate code.

Answer (score 0):

One you get the arraylist, you can iterate it through

```
for(HashMap m : arrayList){
 int first = m.get(SALE_ITEM_ID);
}
```

I don't know if this answers your question`.`
also when you iterate the cursor you can use moveToNext() in the while loop as the condition for it to run

Comment: Sorry, you may need to cast that int.